# Plotly: How to make a jagged line plot look better?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I made a chart showing the number of items purchased over a period of time. The graph seems unreadable to me, hard to get the right perspective. My code below:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df_temp['Date'],
                    y=df_temp['Quantity'],
                    line = dict(color = 'blue'),
                    opacity = 0.3)

layout = dict(title='Purchases of NC coin',)

fig = dict(data=[trace1], layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

And some of my data:

```
Id  Date                Quantity
8   2022-01-16 19:14:56 50814.040553
15  2022-01-12 09:18:01 2563.443420
17  2022-01-11 13:52:38 33055.752836
18  2022-01-11 11:49:54 6483.182959
19  2022-01-11 11:07:48 13005.174783
21  2022-01-11 10:50:20 19605.381370
23  2022-01-11 10:15:30 6561.223602
24  2022-01-11 10:14:44 19762.821100
28  2022-01-07 15:56:50 3307.607665
29  2022-01-07 15:54:30 66868.030051
30  2022-01-07 12:27:07 42683.069577
31  2022-01-07 12:20:51 3423.618394
34  2022-01-05 12:11:57 69607.963793
35  2022-01-05 10:41:48 20370.090947
37  2022-01-05 10:21:22 72415.914082
38  2022-01-05 10:05:04 20687.003754
39  2022-01-05 09:36:53 37410.532342
40  2022-01-05 08:35:06 43815.009603
41  2022-01-04 19:27:27 30581.795021
44  2022-01-03 16:34:41 14290.644375
```

My plot looks like this now:
[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: maybe set the y-axis to logscale?

Comment: At what yaxis scale is the plot readable? what does the plot look like if you remove the point at 1.2M

Comment: A possibility is to group purchases by day. I believe your chart would look prettier. You can use something like this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you've got three options:

#### 1. If no aggregation is desired, use a barplot with `px.bar`

[image]

#### 2. Aggregate by day and use a line plot

[image]

#### 3. Aggregate by day and use a bar plot

[image]

Since you're specifically asking for aesthetics, and not Plotly code, I'm going to use Plotly Express instead of `iplot`. You should too! If for some reason you can't, just let me know.

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'Id': {0: 8,
                          1: 15,
                          2: 17,
                          3: 18,
                          4: 19,
                          5: 21,
                          6: 23,
                          7: 24,
                          8: 28,
                          9: 29,
                          10: 30,
                          11: 31,
                          12: 34,
                          13: 35,
                          14: 37,
                          15: 38,
                          16: 39,
                          17: 40,
                          18: 41,
                          19: 44},
                         'Date': {0: '2022-01-16',
                          1: '2022-01-12',
                          2: '2022-01-11',
                          3: '2022-01-11',
                          4: '2022-01-11',
                          5: '2022-01-11',
                          6: '2022-01-11',
                          7: '2022-01-11',
                          8: '2022-01-07',
                          9: '2022-01-07',
                          10: '2022-01-07',
                          11: '2022-01-07',
                          12: '2022-01-05',
                          13: '2022-01-05',
                          14: '2022-01-05',
                          15: '2022-01-05',
                          16: '2022-01-05',
                          17: '2022-01-05',
                          18: '2022-01-04',
                          19: '2022-01-03'},
                         'Time': {0: '19:14:56',
                          1: '09:18:01',
                          2: '13:52:38',
                          3: '11:49:54',
                          4: '11:07:48',
                          5: '10:50:20',
                          6: '10:15:30',
                          7: '10:14:44',
                          8: '15:56:50',
                          9: '15:54:30',
                          10: '12:27:07',
                          11: '12:20:51',
                          12: '12:11:57',
                          13: '10:41:48',
                          14: '10:21:22',
                          15: '10:05:04',
                          16: '09:36:53',
                          17: '08:35:06',
                          18: '19:27:27',
                          19: '16:34:41'},
                         'Quantity': {0: 50814.040553,
                          1: 2563.44342,
                          2: 33055.752836,
                          3: 6483.182959,
                          4: 13005.174783,
                          5: 19605.38137,
                          6: 6561.223602,
                          7: 19762.8211,
                          8: 3307.607665,
                          9: 66868.030051,
                          10: 42683.069577,
                          11: 3423.618394,
                          12: 69607.963793,
                          13: 20370.090947,
                          14: 72415.914082,
                          15: 20687.003754,
                          16: 37410.532342,
                          17: 43815.009603,
                          18: 30581.795021,
                          19: 14290.644375}})
trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df_temp['Date'],
                    y=df_temp['Quantity'],
                    line = dict(color = 'blue'),
                    opacity = 0.3)

layout = dict(title='Purchases of NC coin',)

# build pandas datetime series
df_temp['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_temp.Date+' '+df_temp.Time)

# # unaggregated barplot
# fig = px.bar(df_temp, x = 'DateTime', y = 'Quantity')
# fig.update_traces(marker_line_color = 'blue')
# fig.update_layout(title='Purchases of NC coin')

# aggregate by day
df_temp = df_temp.groupby(by=[df_temp.DateTime.dt.date]).mean().reset_index()

# # aggregated lineplot
# fig = px.line(df_temp, x = 'DateTime', y = 'Quantity')
# fig.update_traces(marker_line_color = 'blue')
# fig.update_layout(title='Purchases of NC coin')

# aggregated barplot
fig = px.bar(df_temp, x = 'DateTime', y = 'Quantity')
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color = 'blue')
fig.update_layout(title='Purchases of NC coin')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Nice and sweet! Thank you :)